# Sending an int from android to cc2540

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I'm developing an app that connects to a TI cc2540 (the keyfob, actually) and it is intended
to send a "start" flag, that could very well be a simple short, whenever the user presses a button on the android interface to trigger a certain function. ( a GPIO rise in this case )

Now, i'm having trouble writing from android to the cc2540. For what i understand, i should
declare a new service in the cc2540, give it write permissions and try and discover that with 
the android app.

If that's the way to go, how do you check within the cc2540 if the value has changed?
Should it receive a callback when a value has changed? or is there a more appropriate way to do so.

I have tried to use the " static void performPerdicTask(void){...} " on the chip to check if the value has changed, but polling for a value just seems stupid.

Please note that this is the opposite of asking the BLE device to give you a notice when a sensor value in itself changes.. This time, it is the android device giving the value change update.

I have written code to connect and discover services, but it is not important in this case.

Has anybody done something like this?

Comment: The thing you could change would be a **characteristic** *within* a service.  And yes, there will be a method called when it is written - probably a generic one implemented with a case statement to handle the various charateristics. Pretty sure one of the basic peripheral demos has an example of a characteristic that a central can read & write.

Comment: When you send your value to CC2540, the ReadAttrCB() method is triggered. From there, you can follow up with breakpoints in IAR Embedded Workbench to see value of the parameter you want to change.

Comment: I was working with bluegiga bluetooth dongle. I had a similar situation where I need to write value to characteristic. I used get call back if I am registered for it. There should definitely a callback function register for it.